# Launch Jar file located on network through Java Code

Tags: java

I'd like to launch a jar file through an existing running Java application. I've looked into `ProcessBuilder`, `Runtime` and `jproc` and none of them work because they all say the same error:

```
CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

The way I can get it to work is by adding the command: `java -jar <path of network located jar>` in any of the libraries above.

I don't want to do it this way because it messes up with location of paths and such that would run in the context of the network location if you "double clicked" the jar files directly.

Is there a way to run the jar on the network using the "default" JRE on Windows/Mac?

here is example code:

```
String networkLocation = "//appserver/testApp/test.jar";

// new ProcBuilder(networkLocation).withNoTimeout().run();
   
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(networkLocation);
try
{
    pb.start();
} 
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: When you double-click on a jar file (whether it's in a network location or on your local drive), it actually runs `java -jar file.jar` so that is what you have to pass to `ProcessBuilder` too.

Comment: but the context is not local, it's in the folder of the network. So for example files that the application uses that are located on the network can't be found now because the application is running from a local process rather than a network one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to make the working directory using jproc:

```
new ProcBuilder("java", "-jar", networkLocation).withNoTimeout().withWorkingDirectory(new File ("//appserver/testApp/")).run();
```

And also with `Runtime`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-jar", networkLocation}, null, new File("//appserver/testApp/"));
```